# Python fails to json.loads() nested JSON from Kafka

Tags: python, json, apache-kafka

I can't loads() a stringified JSON into a valid JSON, using `json.dumps()`. Here is the code and the result. You can see the erroneous input at error logs. Is there any way I can convert that nested string into valid json? Thanks in advance.

```
    async for value in RedisHandler.get_all_keys(): 
        examined_counter += 1
        task = None
        try:
            task = json.loads(value)
        except Exception as convertJSONException:
            logger.info("Failed converting '%s' into JSON. Skipping." % value)
            continue
```

prints:

```
[--                 TimeoutHandler] Failed converting '{'description': 'dqwdqdq', 'author': 'spp42admin', 'target_project_uuid': '91115b46-54fa-11e8-9a7c-d4c9ef52f9c6', 'tasklist': [{'opuid': '253e3d0d-5514-11e8-9a7c-d4c9ef52f9c6', 'method': 'split-count', 'parameter': '7', 'optional_parameters': '{"codec":"libx264"}', 's3_credentials': {'service_name': 's3', 'aws_access_key_id': '********', 'aws_secret_access_key': '*********', 'endpoint_url': 'http://localhost:9000', 'bucket_uuid': '91115b46-54fa-11e8-9a7c-d4c9ef52f9c6'}, 'srcpath': 'videos/397939d2-550c-11e8-9a7c-d4c9ef52f9c6/test.mp4', 'destpath': 'operations/253e3d0d-5514-11e8-9a7c-d4c9ef52f9c6', 'videoname': 'test.mp4', 'codec': 'mpeg4', 'progress': 1, 'parent_operation_uuid': '253f87b6-5514-11e8-9a7c-d4c9ef52f9c6', 'estimated_timeout': 1526042364}], 's3_credentials': {'service_name': 's3', 'aws_access_key_id': '**********', 'aws_secret_access_key': '***********', 'endpoint_url': 'http://localhost:9000', 'bucket_uuid': '91115b46-54fa-11e8-9a7c-d4c9ef52f9c6'}, 'video_uuid': '397939d2-550c-11e8-9a7c-d4c9ef52f9c6', 'parent_videodocument_uuid': '397939d3-550c-11e8-9a7c-d4c9ef52f9c6', 'parent_project_uuid': '91115b46-54fa-11e8-9a7c-d4c9ef52f9c6', 'progress': 0, 'operation_uuid': '253f87b6-5514-11e8-9a7c-d4c9ef52f9c6'}' into JSON. Skipping.
```

`optional_parameters` is the one causing error.

TLDR: How can I convert string below into JSON, using json.dumps?

'{'description': 'dqwdqdq', 'author': 'spp42admin', 'target_project_uuid': '91115b46-54fa-11e8-9a7c-d4c9ef52f9c6', 'tasklist': [{'opuid': '253e3d0d-5514-11e8-9a7c-d4c9ef52f9c6', 'method': 'split-count', 'parameter': '7', 'optional_parameters': '{"codec":"libx264"}', 's3_credentials': {'service_name': 's3', 'aws_access_key_id': '********', 'aws_secret_access_key': '*********', 'endpoint_url': 'http://localhost:9000', 'bucket_uuid': '91115b46-54fa-11e8-9a7c-d4c9ef52f9c6'}, 'srcpath': 'videos/397939d2-550c-11e8-9a7c-d4c9ef52f9c6/test.mp4', 'destpath': 'operations/253e3d0d-5514-11e8-9a7c-d4c9ef52f9c6', 'videoname': 'test.mp4', 'codec': 'mpeg4', 'progress': 1, 'parent_operation_uuid': '253f87b6-5514-11e8-9a7c-d4c9ef52f9c6', 'estimated_timeout': 1526042364}]}'

Comment: Those backslashes should not be there. What does it look like if you print out the result in javascript? It should be: `'{"foo":"bar","foo_two":{"bar":"baz"}}'`

Comment: @dpwrussell yes, I tested it in JavaScript, nothing seems wrong. Nested json is successfully stringified. However, I can't use `json.loads()` on that. At python-side, I print the response I get from JavaScript, I see those backslashes. Maybe because it gets serialized /deserialized during the translocation.

Comment: To be honest the response isn't exactly valid JSON. Can you try to do `json.dumps()` and see what it gives you ? Maybe you will be able to load the result.

Comment: @Wald It turns out that I couldn't put it into foo,bar,baz. I posted the actual code and error message. Maybe it can help you figure things out. Thanks a lot for the effort.

Comment: How do you send it to the backend? Also, I don't really know flask, but wouldn't you expect the data to be in `request`? How do you get that, `request.get_json()`?

Comment: Also, you need to be more careful with your AWS credentials. You need to invalidate the key you just posted here.

Comment: @dpwrussell thats just a docker container that I deploy for testing purposes, but thank you for the effort. about the flask thing, it turns out it's not related to javascript or flask. the problem is pure python. I simply can't convert the string listed in error log into a json file.

Comment: If what you have is double encoded JSON (i.e. a dict which has been JSON encoded, which has then been used in a dict which has been JSON encoded. Then what you should have is: `'{"foo": "bar", "foo_two": "{\\"bar\\": \\"baz\\"}"}'`.

Comment: @AliYılmaz There is still some this part of the json causing the problem `'optional_parameters': '{"codec":"libx264"}',`. It most likely should be `'optional_parameters': [{'codec':'libx264'}],`

Comment: @AliYılmaz Would highly suggest to check if JSON in the message broker ( kafka ) is a valid JSON based on the previous comment it is not. And this is causing you this issues.